# Recommendations for packaging design books?

Tags: resource-recommendations, packaging

I've mostly done design for digital spaces and I have a huge project that we can either outsource or do in-house. I'd prefer doing it in-house as it adds a lot of value to one's portfolio.

A few years ago I became interested in web design. The starting place? I got a book. It was Learning Web Design 4th Edition by Jennifer N Robbins. Life-changing experience. That book single-handedly made me inspired enough to pursue web design. The rest was online research, of course, but by the time I neared the end of the book, I could create amazing, functional, responsive websites.

So, here I am asking for recommendations. Where should I start? Some of the more packaging design-inclined people here might have a great deal of experience with this and I'd like their help.

I tried Google, Quora, design forums, etc. but all the favorites and top lists don't quite match up. I am finding it difficult to choose the first, definitive resource I'll need.

Comment: Hello! I might be able to answer this (might take a day or two though)... I've edited out the last question because it should be its own question. We already have quite a few questions on color so be sure to search before asking.

Comment: With regards to internal production, note that packaging design is not for the faint of heart...if you can tell us more about your current experience with print, and the field of the project (food, medical, cosmetic, etc.) that would be helpful.

Comment: My current experience in print is limited. I have designed marketing collateral, packaging designs, advertisement collateral like posters, flyers, standees and the bottom line is that I have a functional grasp of the tools and resources required for print work, including the technialities surrounding bleeds, types of printing, typography, and so on.